# Anchor tag block property on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I made my tablet and mobile menu horizontals [click](http://prntscr.com/dcnr1m).I made my andchor elements to display as block elements because i wanted my li elements to be on full screen,but when i used `width:100%` it didn't work and i asked in this forum,some guys told me i need to make my anchor elements to `display:block` and remove my style from my li elements.And it worked,but the problem now is when you are on mobile or tablet device,and click on menu that have sub-menus,it is redirecting you to  page instead of dropping menu down.Can somebody help me fix that.
THere is my code:

```css
/******************************************
             Tablet Menu Style
*******************************************/
.tablet-menu{
display:none;
background:#000;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:0.7;
z-index:1001;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.tablet-menu.show{
display:block;
}
.tablet-menu ul{
position:relative;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.tablet-menu li{
color:#FFF;
background:#000;
}
.tablet-menu li a{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: "Roboto Slab", Times, Georgia, serif;
font-weight:bold;
border-radius:2px;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
position:relative;
display:block;
padding-top:4%;
padding-bottom:4%;
}
.tablet-menu ul li ul{
display:none;
}
.tablet-menu li:hover ul, .tablet-menu li ul li ul {
display:block;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}
.tablet-menu li:last-child{
border:none;
}
.tablet-menu li > a:after{
content: "\33";
font-family: "ElegantIcons";
}
.tablet-menu li a:only-child:after, .tablet-menu li li a:after{
content:"";
}
/*
.tablet-menu li .sub-menu a:last-child:after{
content:"32";
}
*/
.tablet-menu li a:hover{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tablet-menu">
     <ul class="tablet-menu-ul">
            <li>
             <a>test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a></a>                                                                        <ul>
                 <li>
                  <a>test1</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                    <a></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
                <li>
                  <a>test2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>test3</a>
                 <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a>test4</a>
                  </li>
                 </ul>
                 </li>
                </nav>
             </div>
```

I want when user click on element that have sub-menu,that sub-menu to show.
If you need any more info,write here.
EDIT:I am working on wordpress i think i have re-maked the menu code here,because in wordpress its just PHP code.

Comment: Please include the `HTML` as well.

Comment: Done  
Need 15 char to pubish comment ;D

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will be not achieve using simple CSS. You have to use JS for this and slight changes in your HTML.

1. Insert  into  if it has children
2. Use JS, on `has-child` click display sub menu and vice versa.

Make sure you've added `event.preventDefault()` while handling `has-child` click event.

Or

Use third party plugin which will handle such situation.
This is best I've got and using peacefully until now - http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Cheers!

Comment: I tried somethinf like This: http://prntscr.com/dcvwg1 but it just removed function of menu,when you click on something nothing happens ;/
I don't really know how professional sites are making that happen ;/

Comment: I think you should try the readymade plugin which will help you more quickly .

Comment: I don't like to use plugins i love to write all by myself,i made a bit what i wanted will publish result in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I made some close thing to what i wanted as a end result here is the jquery code.

```js
$('.mobile-menu li').click(function(ev) {
    if($(this).children('ul').is(':visible'))
        return true;
    if($(this).children('ul').toggle("slow").length)
        return false;
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```